# Why does Tim Henson look so cool? (technically)

Tags: guitar

A more formal way to phrase this would be, "what makes Tim's playing so aesthetically pleasing?".

Him:

Some covers:

Although the music is paramount, the visual aesthetics of playing are also important. Can anyone pin down some specifics (in the mechanics of playing, not in the his body looks)? And does anyone know how this sort of playing is achieved? Is it just lots of practice?
Some things I've noticed:

- He makes more use of the space above the fretboard
- He makes more movements with his whole hand/arm rather than just fingers
- He keep his fingers very straight
- He makes precise movements that extend over long distances (e.g. when he puts the finger on the low E for the bend)

Answer (score 1):

In general, people appear cool when they don't seem to care much or be working hard, especially when they are doing something extremely difficult. Someone who shows the effort of what they are doing never looks cool, even though they may still be quite impressive.

In this case, his body seems very relaxed, and his movements are very precise, but don't seem calculated or mechanical.

My best advice to you is to not try to emulate whatever "cool" things Tim might be doing. If you become good enough to make very hard things look effortless, "cool" will come along with that. Trying to emulate specific elements of style that don't come out of the music will just make you look like you're trying too hard --and nothing is less cool than that.